# HTML/vue.js - disable select list when checked

Tags: html, vue.js

I have a form with the field "age".  There are two possible scenarios: either I check the "unknow" box and then you can't enter/select an age (in other words, this option should be disabled) or the box is not checked, and then you can enter the age. However, I can't do the first scenario at all. Here is my code:

```
<div class="row mb-3">
<label for="age" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Age </label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="number"class="col-sm-3 col-form-control" min="0" max="120" step="1" id="age">
</div>
<div class="row mb-3">
<label class="col-sm-1 col-form-check-label"> Unknow </label>
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="check1" name="option1" value="something">
</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do this with vue.js? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I think it's possible to do it with plain old JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your first scenario.

```js
const checkBox = document.getElementById('check1')
const input = document.getElementById('age')

checkBox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    input.disabled = true
  } else {
    input.disabled = false
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="row mb-3">
  <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Age </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="number" class="col-sm-3 col-form-control" min="0" max="120" step="1" id="age">
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-check-label"> Unknow </label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="check1" name="option1" value="something">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with both. The thing is, you should understand how it works in plain JavaScript first before jumping to any kind of JavaScript framework, hope that makes sense

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      checkedStatus: false,
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="row mb-3" id="app">
  <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Age </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="number" class="col-sm-3 col-form-control" min="0" max="120" step="1" id="age" :disabled="checkedStatus">
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-check-label"> Unknow </label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="check1" name="option1" value="something" @change="checkedStatus=!checkedStatus">
  </div>
</div>
```